# Capture Shell Script Output and Do a String Match to execute the next command?

Tags: bash, shell

i have a Shell script doing the following two commands, connecting to a remote server and putting files via SFTP, lets called it "execute.sh"

```
sftp -b /usr/local/outbox/send.sh username@example.com
mv /usr/local/outbox/DD* /usr/local/outbox/completed/
```

Then in my "send.sh" i have following commands to be executed on the remote server.

```
cd ExampleFolder/outbox
put Files_*
bye
```

Now my problem is

**If the first command "sftp -b" fails due to a remote connection error some network problem, it still moves the files into the "completed folder" which is incorrect, so i want some way to do the next command "mv" to be executed only if the first command to "sftp" is successfully connected.**

Can we do this by enhancing this shell script ? or some work around ?

My Shell is Bash.

Answer (score 4):

Simply insert `&&` between the two commands:

```
sftp -b /usr/local/outbox/send.sh username@example.com && \
mv /usr/local/outbox/DD* /usr/local/outbox/completed/
```

If the first fails, the second one will not run.

Alternatively, you can check the exit code of the first command explicitly. The exit code of the last command is always saved in `$?`, and it is `0` if the command succeeded:

```
sftp -b /usr/local/outbox/send.sh username@example.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  mv /usr/local/outbox/DD* /usr/local/outbox/completed/
fi
```

If you really wanted to capture the *output* of the first command, you could run it in `$(...)` and store the value in a variable:

```
sftpOutput="$(sftp -b /usr/local/outbox/send.sh username@example.com)"
```

and then use this variable in further checks, e.g. match it against a pattern in the next `if`.

Comment: You can also simply do: `if sftp ...; then mv ...; fi`  No need to explicitly reference `$?`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes... But if the command in question itself becomes longer and then runs over multiple lines glued together with backslashes, I somehow find it more comfortable to reference `$?` instead of cramming the entire thing into `if`. But yes, you are right.

Comment: If the line becomes long, you can put everything on its own line: `if<newline> 10 lines of ugly commands <newline> then <newline> ...`

Comment: Yes, but then it's maybe even preferable to omit the `if` altogether and terminate the long ugly command by a `&&` instead and then append the next command. I just don't like to have my `if`s too far away from the `then`s and `else`s, that's not a hard rule, that's just my personal preference.